# In wso2 Integartion studio Exception occurred while connecting to gmail backend server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

[2023-03-14 14:45:36,066]  WARN {TargetHandler} - ERROR_CODE = 101500, STATE_DESCRIPTION = Exception occurred when Server establishing a connection to the backend, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_READY, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = I/O exception : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, TARGET_HOST = 142.250.183.170, TARGET_PORT = 443, TARGET_CONTEXT = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=connectors%0D%0datamapper%0repository%0D%0A, HTTP_METHOD = GET, TRIGGER_TYPE = api, TRIGGER_NAME = SendMails, REMOTE_ADDRESS = [www.googleapis.com/142.250.183.170:443](http://www.googleapis.com/142.250.183.170:443), CONNECTION = http-outgoing-1

This same endpoint tried in postman with gmail oauth consent screen credentials and it is working fine. In WSO2 Integration studio using the Gmail connector I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a mismatch between the postman request and the WSO2 Integration studio request. Let's enable the wire logs, compare the request, identify the differences, and try to correct those. To enable the wire logs, navigate to the place where the integration studio resides, find the runtime, open to the /conf/log4j2.properties and enable the wire logs as mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/@kasunaratthanage/enabling-wire-logs-log4j2-properties-in-wso2-enterprise-integrator-6-6-0-a5a251db139a) article.